# Dynamic Chart from selection of any KPI boxes in Qlik

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I am new to the development of Qlik and I am in the middle of building my first dashboard in Qlik. I currently have a dashboard that I am developing that has 11 Multi KPIs added on its Main Sheet  that shows various Summarised Values for the Measures that it is showing and that works very well.

What I am looking to do now is to add a single chart with the space that I have left (GRAPH 1) (attached image of example of dashboard) but what I would like is to default the chart to show the first KPI's trend over a 13 week period (will create this). My main question is, is it possible for this chart to be dynamic so that I am able to single click on any of the KPI's to change the chart to show the clicked KPI's chart?

As when the KPI is double clicked this will go onto a separate dashboard so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Would appreciate if somebody could clarify if this is something that can be achieved as not sure if it's something I will have to do using some Javascript or if there is a feature that will allow me to build this in Qlik itself.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the chart to always be the same kind of chart? For example, always a bar chart?

Comment: Thanks CvP, I was thinking that if I could have a 13 week view on the chart so a line chart for every KPI so would be happy with the same chart on this dashboard.

Comment: I can think of three options:
1) Using the "tabbed container extension" that is included in the dashboard bundle. Thing is, that is limited to 5 visualizations.
2) Make a single line chart that depends on a variable for it's title/measure/dimension and combine this with a filter object where you can change this variable (all options are one of your KPI's). This does change your page a little since you need to have a filter object as well;
3) Achieve this with alternate dimensions/measures. I don't know what the limit is on this, but you could try fitting all the KPI's in.

Comment: Thanks CvP, will look through your suggestions and come back to you. Thanks once again.

Comment: If you chose one of them, let me know and I might be able to help you with an example/ real answer.

Comment: Thanks CvP, I am going try with the Tabbed Container Extension you mentioned and see how that works, the limitation of 5 visualizations is obviously the downside to it, but first step is to see if it is doable.

Comment: Hi CvP, I have managed to created the Tabbed Container Extension, which works fine, but not what I was hoping for. Your 2nd option, 2) Make a single line chart that depends on a variable for it's title/measure/dimension and combine this with a filter object where you can change this variable (all options are one of your KPI's). This does change your page a little since you need to have a filter object as well; seemed the most interesting. At the moment, all the KPI's are dependent on variables so not sure how I change this to select which KPI to display. Care to explain further?

Comment: Do you still need help? I can make you an example if desired

Comment: Hi CvP, an example would be brilliant, if you can create one that would help me out immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached an example that includes 2 solutions:

1. First one is made using alternative measures, so for every KPI I made an alternative measure. In my previous comment I mentioned there might be a limit to the amount of alternative dimensions/measures, but after some testing it doesn't seem like it (at least 12 work). The downside to this method is that it doesn't save the order of the alternative measures, but it changes every time you make a selection.
2. Second solution is made using a filter object, as explained in my previous comment:

> Make a single line chart that depends on a variable for it's
>   title/measure/dimension and combine this with a filter object where
>   you can change this variable (all options are one of your KPI's). This
>   does change your page a little since you need to have a filter object
>   as well;

Both should work, but in the end it comes down to personal preference.

Attachment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wRgStl23DfcI5arQTZmt3w_0DEtW5iuf/view?usp=sharing

Since I can't garantee this google drive link will be up forever, here is it in steps:

**Solution 1: Alternative measures:**

In the Data load editor I made a new section with the following dummy data:

```
    LOAD * Inline [
Weeks, KPI1, KPI2, KPI3, KPI4, KPI5, KPI6, KPI7, KPI8, KPI9, KPI10, KPI11, KPI12
1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 3
2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 5, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 5, 3
3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3
4, 4, 8, 1, 7, 6, 4, 4, 8, 1, 7, 6, 3
5, 5, 10, 2, 0, 7, 5, 5, 10, 2, 0, 7, 3
6, 6, 12, 2, 9, 7, 6, 6, 12, 2, 9, 7, 3
7, 7, 14, 3, 13, 7, 7, 7, 14, 3, 13, 7, 3
8, 8, 16, 3, 6, 8, 8, 8, 16, 3, 6, 8, 3
9, 9, 18, 4, 1, 8, 9, 9, 18, 4, 1, 8, 3
10, 10, 4, 3, 9, 10, 10, 10, 4, 3, 9, 10, 3
11, 11, 5, 3, 9, 10, 11, 11, 5, 3, 9, 10, 3
12, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 3
];
```

Then I added a "Line chart" object to a page and gave it the measure "Weeks". I also added a measure with expression: KPI1. Then I added 11 alternatives measures the exact same way for every KPI. So like this:

[image: Alternative measures]

This should result in this:

[image: End result Alternative measures]

**Solution 2: Filter object**

In the Data load editor I made a new section with the following dummy data:

```
LOAD * Inline [
Weeks, KPI1, KPI2, KPI3, KPI4, KPI5, KPI6, KPI7, KPI8, KPI9, KPI10, KPI11, KPI12
1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 3
2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 5, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 5, 3
3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3
4, 4, 8, 1, 7, 6, 4, 4, 8, 1, 7, 6, 3
5, 5, 10, 2, 0, 7, 5, 5, 10, 2, 0, 7, 3
6, 6, 12, 2, 9, 7, 6, 6, 12, 2, 9, 7, 3
7, 7, 14, 3, 13, 7, 7, 7, 14, 3, 13, 7, 3
8, 8, 16, 3, 6, 8, 8, 8, 16, 3, 6, 8, 3
9, 9, 18, 4, 1, 8, 9, 9, 18, 4, 1, 8, 3
10, 10, 4, 3, 9, 10, 10, 10, 4, 3, 9, 10, 3
11, 11, 5, 3, 9, 10, 11, 11, 5, 3, 9, 10, 3
12, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 12, 5, 8, 9, 10, 3
];

LOAD * Inline [
KPI,
KPI1,
KPI2,
KPI3,
KPI4,
KPI5,
KPI6,
KPI7,
KPI8,
KPI9,
KPI10,
KPI11,
KPI12
];
```

Then I added a "Line chart" object to a page and gave it the measure "Weeks". I also added a measure with the following expression:

```
= if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI1') = 1, KPI1,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI2') = 1, KPI2,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI3') = 1, KPI3,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI4') = 1, KPI4,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI5') = 1, KPI5,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI6') = 1, KPI6,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI7') = 1, KPI7,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI8') = 1, KPI8,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI9') = 1, KPI9,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI10') = 1, KPI10,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI11') = 1, KPI11,
  if(WildMatch(GetFieldSelections(KPI), 'KPI12') = 1, KPI12,
))))))))))))
```

After that I added a new "Filter object" to the page with dimension: KPI. As a final step I go to "Fields" -> right click "KPI" -> click "Field settings" -> check "Always one selected value" -> click "Save".

So like this:
[image: check "Always one selected value"]

And that's it, now you have a filter object that influences your line chart.

Hope it helped, if anything isn't clear, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much, going through this now and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thanks CvP, that has helped me out alot, not exactly what I wanted, but definitely another solution and definitely gives me options than the the restrictions of the 5 tabs. I have managed to get the sample from above working, going try it directly with my table data now. Much appreciated.

Comment: CvP, just wanted to say, thank you so much, I went with Solution 1 and I have managed to integrate this with my dataset and this works pretty well, just what I wanted. So pleased.

Comment: I know the question has been answered but for future learning, from my original image, in the 3rd box where you see all the costings £300,000 etc, this is split between 3 KPI's, is there a way to create 1 line chart with the 3 figures together and then save it down. Within the main chart I can then add this 1 chart with the 3 measures merged. Just something I thought would be useful for future purposes so thought I would ask. Thanks once again.

Comment: @MichaelOwen Glad you liked it, here is my paypal: just joking ;). Regarding your new question, do you want to see 1 line or 3 lines in the linechart? So do you want to see a line for the 300k, the 120k and 180k? Or just 1 line for the total, 600k? Happy to help.

Comment: CvP, lol. In 1 chart I would like to see 3 lines and I have been able to do this by moving the 3 KPIs in to the main measure section, but then this gives me multiple drop downs to then add the alternate measures and thats why it doesn't work.

Comment: After a bit of thinking, I don't think you can do it using 'solution 1' (or it will look terrible, like you experienced), I do think you can do it using 'solution 2'. I think if you use the filter object as the legend and hide the legend on the line chart, you can sneakily add two extra measures that only show when you select the "300k,120k, 180k" KPI.Don't know if that's worth the trouble though.